# CraftABrew tubing immersion exposed to air overnight

Tags: fermentation, yeast, beer

[image: West Coast IPA Day2]

I’m trying craftabrew home brewing kit(West Coast IPA). There was a lot of yeast activity on Day 1 after putting it in the container. Day 2 I removed the tubing from the steel vessel, cleaned the pile by just adding water into the tube and put it back into the vessel. But looks like the tube fell out of the vessel in the morning and I don’t know how long it’s been exposed to outside air.

Is my brew spoilt? If so how do I check? Is there a way to save it still if it’s spoilt. It’s turned into a nice orange on top and not brown. I’m not sure if it’s still good

I can see some bubbles but not a lot coming out of the tube. On day 1 it was frothy and messy everywhere. It was completely green froth.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely won't be sure if something infected it until at least the bottling stage.

However, the beer is probably fine. During that stage of fermentation, a healthy krousen and layer of CO2 is protecting your beer. Unless a bunch of bugs managed to fall into it, you are likely fine- and in any case it cannot harm you.

As an aside based on your picture, make sure your fermenter isn't getting sunlight on it. A brown paper bag or t-shirt over the fermenter will usually do the trick (perhaps it is here for the sake of this picture- and in that case ignore me).

Comment: Thanks, that explains everything. craft-a-brew kit didn’t explain about clearly about where the first 24-72 hours of fermenting should be done so I kept it on the table. I just wrapped it using a TShirt and stored in a dark place as soon as I saw your answer. 2 weeks starts from today.

Comment: Also, I’m planning to add crushed mango along with dry hops by the end of the process a week before bottling. Similar to this video: https://youtu.be/dMYGOcLwtQk  . That should be fine right? Or do you suggest not to add in because this is a fermented in a jar kind of a thing as opposed to a big container.

Comment: It should be fine, just be aware you may lose some of the final product when you add more organic matter due to more things settling.

Comment: Let me know if you have any thoughts about this: https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/q/25207/18482