# Didn’t completely add a stopper CraftABrew

Tags: fermentation, yeast, beer, carboy

[image: carboy with stopper]

I want to know if this is a blunder. I put some water but I didn’t have the lid that I’m holding on my hand. It’s been 2 weeks like this and I noticed it when I was adding cascade hops at the end of 2 weeks of fermentation.

Please do let me know if this is a blunder and I need to pour out my beer and start fresh.

This is from craft a brew west coast ipa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a gravity reading and taste it!

it looks like it fermented well, did it come out of the top?

if you had the white cap on it then that is definitely OK. CO2 is heavier than air, so would have protected the beer, and your white cap would have stopped bigger bogies from getting in.

but all in the taste, right?

Comment: What should be the ideal gravity reading? I didn’t get it with the kit but I’m willing to order it. I’ll need to wait for another week to taste it. I also need to filter out some of the hops that’s on top.

Comment: The gravity should be lower than the reading at day one or the day before... if you dont have a hydrometer then you should really get one (about £4.00) and watch some youtube on how to use it (but it really is simple). Every brew WILL be different even between the same beer, this is why you need a take readings.

Comment: For "filter out some hops", once ferment is complete just syphon to clean bucket/bottles or pressure barrel leaving the hops and sediment behind, to allow for second ferment and carbonation.

Comment: I’ll do that today. I need to find another vessel to syphon it to.